# Zurb vs. Bootstrap themes: About performance

Tags: theming, performance

I'm trying to decide to use [Foundation](https://www.drupal.org/project/zurb_foundation) or [Bootstrap](https://www.drupal.org/project/bootstrap) as a base theme for a redesign, but even if Foundation have a lot of strengths (native sass support as I've read), it seems that it is waaay bigger than Bootstrap.

**Zurb compressed file is about 585.16 KB while Bootstrap is 103.27 KB.**

Bootstrap is being used by way more people, but that doesn't necessarily mean that it's better. Any insight about their performance?

I've read several articles about their performance, **but none about their "Drupal versions" of each theme.**

**So, my question is: Does a much, much bigger base theme impacts into performance?**

**It seems that it does, but** I've read somewhere that Bootstrap and Foundation are almost equal in terms of performance. How can that be?

Comment: There are just too many factors to tell reliably. Only answer could be: test yourself, with your configuration and your visitors' behaviour characteristics.

Comment: Premature optimization.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Drupal [Bootstrap](https://www.drupal.org/project/bootstrap) is just a wrapper for the [Bootstrap Framework](http://getbootstrap.com/). When you download that, the compressed size increases by about 200 Kb.  However, I don't think size is a good metric for theme performance.

Foundation has a very limited number of UI elements, it just gives you the foundation to build your own theme upon. Bootstrap provides almost every UI element you can think of. If you want to design your own CSS carefully, to give your site a personal design, go with Foundation.  If you just want to do rapid prototyping or to have  a responsive site up quickly and with little effort, go with Bootstrap.

As for performance, I haven't spotted any clear differences between these in the context of Drupal. Btw.: I don't think the Drupal versions should differ from those on other platforms, as most of the code is the same for all platforms. The Drupal versions are just wrapped to fit into Drupal's theme system.